# Why am I getting an AttributeError?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to store the first name and last name of a user in my datatbase upon hitting the `submit` button so that next time when I manually check in `Terminal` what's inside my database, I can see exactly what the user inputted.

This is the error I'm getting:
[image]

I'm assuming the error is coming from my `views.py` file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Person
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('firstName')
        last_name = request.POST.get('lastName')
        if first_name and last_name:
            user = Person.objects.create(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name)
            user.save()
    return render('request', 'music/index.html')

def detail(request, user_id): # Testing out page 2
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Page # (testing this out) " + str(user_id) + "</h2>")
```

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of the error message. Click on the link that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view", then copy and paste the text here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is passing `'request'` (string literal) to [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) which expected [`Request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object as the first parameter.

Pass the `request` parameter of the view function:

---

```
return render('request', 'music/index.html')
```

should be:

```
return render(request, 'music/index.html')
```

Comment: Ok, this got rid of the `AttributeError` but whenever I type in a first and last name and click submit, it's not showing up in my database.

Comment: @bojack, Please post a separated question with details.

Comment: That's the question.  How do I get my submit button to work so that whenever I input a first and last name, it appears in my database.

Comment: @bojack, not in comment, but in *NEW* question post.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry about that and thank you for your solution.